# How to trigger the handler of a button?

Tags: r, button, user-interface, handler, gwidgets

How is it possible to trigger the handler of a button in `gWidgets2`? Take this example:

```
w <- gwindow("Buttons", visible=FALSE)
g <- ggroup(cont=w, horizontal=FALSE)

## various buttons

## without icon
b2 <- gbutton("ouvrir", cont=g)

## with a handler
b4 <- gbutton("click me", cont=g, handler=function(h,...) {
    if(svalue(b2) == "open")
        svalue(b2) <- "ouvrir"
    else
        svalue(b2) <- "open"
})

visible(w) <- TRUE
```

I can trigger the handler of `b4` by using the mouse and "physically" clicking on the button. But how can I achieve this via some R code? I am hoping for something like `activateHandler(b4)` or similar.

Comment: Give the function a name before assigning it as the handler and then call the function directly seems like a decent way to do this.

Comment: Indeed! Feel free to transform this in an answer and I'll accept that.

Comment: `b$invoke_change_handler()` should also work with `gWidgets2` where `b` is the button object.

Comment: @jverzani Nice! This works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the suggestions in the comments, I can either via `b4$invoke_change_handler()`. Or by redefining the handler as a separate function:

```
w <- gwindow("Buttons", visible=FALSE)
g <- ggroup(cont=w, horizontal=FALSE)
## various buttons
## without icon
h2 <- function(h,...) {
if(svalue(b2) == "open")
svalue(b2) <- "ouvrir"
else
svalue(b2) <- "open"
}
b2 <- gbutton("ouvrir", cont=g)
## with a handler
b4 <- gbutton("click me", cont=g, handler=h2)
visible(w) <- TRUE
```

and then calling that: `h2()`.